# INSERT INTO code returns a Compiler Error: Expected: End of Statement

Tags: ms-access, vba

I wrote simple code to insert a record in a test data table.  Followed the MSDN example but cannot get past the compile error.  I have tried it with the recordset and with the table name alone.  Same error.

```
Private Sub cmdCommitChg_Click()
'this is my tester environment
Dim ztemp1, ztemp2, ztemp3 As String  'these are dummy data to append to the table
Dim tblInsert As String
Dim dbsDonors As DAO.Database
Dim rcdTempTester As DAO.Recordset

Set rcdTempTester = dbsDonors.OpenRecordset("tblTempTester")
ztemp1 = "TempId"
ztemp2 = "TempEntity"
ztemp3 = "tempName"
INSERT INTO rcdTempTester!tblTempTester (id_members, id_entity, member_Name) VALUES (ztemp1, ztemp2, ztemp3)

End Sub
```

Comment: I believe you should `set dbsdonors=currentdb` or other database before you open the recordset.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing VBA and SQL. Do this:

```
Private Sub cmdCommitChg_Click()

    'this is my tester environment
    Dim ztemp1 As String
    Dim ztemp2 As String
    Dim ztemp3 As String  

    Dim tblInsert As String
    Dim dbsDonors As DAO.Database
    Dim rcdTempTester As DAO.Recordset

    ztemp1 = "TempId"
    ztemp2 = "TempEntity"
    ztemp3 = "tempName"

    Set rcdTempTester = dbsDonors.OpenRecordset("tblTempTester")
    rcdTempTester.AddNew
        rcdTempTester(ztemp1).Value = <some id>
        rcdTempTester(ztemp2).Value = <some entity>
        rcdTempTester(ztemp3).Value = <some name>
    rcdTempTester.Update
    rcdTempTester.Close

    Set rcdTempTester = Nothing
    Set dbsDonors = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: This code returns a Compile Error:  Method or data member not found... I see that there may be an issue with the Active X controls and I tried removing the *.exd files... did not fix the problem. @Gustav  Do you think I have a properties setting on the form or environment that is causing the issue?  It seems like this should be pretty straight forward.  Thanks for your response!

Comment: I see. You wished to pass the name of the fields to update, then the values. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

I started over and now things are working.  Attached is the simple code to add a record (and it works).

```
Private Sub cmdAddNew_Click()
Dim dbsDonors As DAO.Database
Dim rstTester As DAO.Recordset
Dim zBEN As String

zBEN = "zip1"

Set dbsDonors = CurrentDb
Set rstTester = dbsDonors.OpenRecordset("tblTester")

rstTester.AddNew
rstTester!id_members = "newData"
rstTester.Update
End Sub
```